# Call a voter in a voter

Tags: symfony

I've a voter to decide if someone can see an object A, it's work fine, well.
But, I want to do something like this: a user can see an Object B if he can see one of the object A linked on B, and with other test.

To do it, I want call a voter in another voter, to take a decision.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html#checking-for-roles-inside-a-voter

> Calling `decide()` on the `AccessDecisionManager` is essentially the same as calling `isGranted()` from a controller or other places

Also, you need to pass the other object to the `decide()` as third argument

Comment: Thanks, I've find it but gave my object as first argument :/ That's why I've thought it's just used for role. But i'ts work, thank you very much.